# Encoding HTML & Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, encoding, ip

i'm building a site, and my ip needs to be in the javascript for a server.

But i want to hide this. I allready using ioncube for that, but when you press f12 example in google chrome, you see still the source and the ip. How to hide this with a encoding.
Example when my ip is. 123.123.123.123 that when you check the source that it comes as example: H4w5EK4ksfdk#%sfsldfs.

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Does your application use the ip in string format or integer format?

Comment: I dont realy understand, i'm sorry, my english is bad. But it needs to show in a encrypted string and it needs to run in the real ip.

Comment: If the browser uses the IP to connect to a server, there's nothing you can do to hide it from the user. The user can always find out where the browser is connecting to, one way or another.

Comment: Thats true, it is never full protected, but with ioncube is the source protected but with f12 you can still see it, so i have see on time, was a javascript code, that shows a string encrypted.
I needs to echo in website, its a javascript code that needs te ip.

Comment: Why do you want to hide your IP? How should the client connect to you without knowing it?

Comment: If your considerations are for security then don't pass anything to the client. With todays browsers anything and everything can be tampered with on the clients computer.

Comment: Also, if your server security relies on people not knowing its IP you have bigger problems.

Comment: So there is nothing to protect it a little bit better ?

Answer (score 3):

If thought through to final conclusion, this cannot be achieved. JavaScript is always transported from the server to the client (browser) in source form, so any IP address or domain name will be visible.

You can use some sort of obfuscation (google for "Javascript obfuscation"), but while this will create a threshold, it will be an easily surmountable one for any attacker stubborn enough.

The thing you can't work around is: If you want the browser to be able to extract and understand the address, it is also possible for a human being with a JS debugger to extract and understand it. Besides, any developer tool such as Chrome "Dev tools" or Firebug will reveal any access to this address.

Comment: Thank you, this have to protect it a little bit more :)